# Keep Line Break on Textarea and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, line, break

I coded some Form to send Text to MySql. One of my Problem is to keep the line break. Found some Code over Google but i don't have any idea how i could use it. Some tries was not really successful.

The Code i found is that below which i don't know how to set up.

```
 function my_nl2br($string){
    $string = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $string);
        if(preg_match_all('/\<pre\>(.*?)\<\/pre\>/', $string, $match)){
            foreach($match as $a){
            foreach($a as $b){
            $string = str_replace('<pre>'.$b.'</pre>', "<pre>".str_replace("<br />", "", $b)."</pre>", $string);
            }
        }
    }
return $string;
}
```

Another code i found is this but if i try to read it from database the line break will not work.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $text = trim($_POST['text']); 
    $text = stripslashes($text); 
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text); 

    echo 'you entered:<br><br>' . nl2br($text); 
}
```

This is my Code where i want to implant it.

```
  if(isset($_POST['title']))
      {
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']));
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
        $applepart = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['applepart']));
        $partnumber = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['partnumber']));
        $productcode = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['productcode']));
        $compatibility = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['compatibility']));
        $url_bild = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['url_bild']));
        $price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['price']));
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `adressbuch` (`title`,`description`,`applepart`,`partnumber`,`productcode`,`compatibility`,`url_bild`,`price`) VALUES ('$title','$description','$applepart','$partnumber','$productcode','$compatibility','$url_bild','$price')");
        if (!$insert)
        {
          die('Eintrag konnte nicht gespeichert werden: ' . mysql_error());
        }
      }

    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="?page= ">
      <span>Neuer Eintrag:</span> <br />
      <span>Title</span><input type="text" name="title" /> <br />
      <span>Description</span><textarea cols="16" rows="5"  name="description"></textarea> <br />
      <span>Apple Part</span><input type="text" name="applepart" /> <br />
      <span>Part Number</span><input type="text" name="partnumber" /> <br />
      <span>Product Code</span><input type="text" name="productcode" /> <br />
      <span>Compatibility</span><input type="text" name="compatibility" /> <br />
      <span>Image</span><input type="text" name="url_bild" /> <br />
      <span>Price</span><input type="text" name="price" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Speichern"/> <br />
    </form>
```

cheers guys

Comment: Is the input in the textarea supposed to be some HTML code? If so, line breaks in HTML must be specified with the _br_ tag. If input is in plain text, you have to escape it. Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: No. Should be just plain text

Comment: Okay, then I think you should HTML escape `$_POST['title']`, then apply `nl2br` and eventually sql escaping.

Comment: thanks acondolu but as beginner was that my question how to add it :)

Comment: I got it work.. Thanks acondolu :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store *title* in the database, try:

```
$title = real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title'])));
```